# Bash script to evenly split up files and folders

Tags: bash, shell

I have a set of files and folders like so:

```
├── controller
│   └── controller.txt
├── hello.txt
├── hi.txt
├── me.txt
└── model
    └── user.txt
```

The contents in here will change often, new files, files deleted, folders added, folders deleted, etc. I need a way to split up these files evenly in 3rds (though this might change).

By split up I mean, I just need to keep the first 3rd of files.  I'll also need another script to keep the 2nd 3rd of files, etc.

Here's my initial thought though it doesn't quite work:

```
ls -1 | wc -l | head -n / 3 | xargs rm
```

Update for context:

I'm using a parallel ci tool and I only want 1/3 of my test files to run on one server at a time. So I need the script on one server to just be:

server 1:

```
├── controller
│   └── controller.txt
├── hello.txt
```

server 2:

```
├── hi.txt
├── me.txt
```

server 3:

```
└── model
    └── user.txt
```

Comment: What kind of order do you use to determine the thirds?

Comment: `rm` isn't going to help you "to keep the first 3rd of files (etc)". So the result you need is unclear to me. Consider editing  your question to show what that block of files will look like after your successful script runs. (Yes, and what order are you using). Good luck.

Comment: @fedorqui - order is irrelevant at the moment.

Comment: @shellter - sorry I just need to keep 1/3 of the files for each server, please see my update.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example script. You can replace echo $file_name with any other command like mv, cp, rm etc.

```
#!/bin/sh
# the helper file needs to be outside of the stucture, when the script is ran
find -type f > ../helper_file
NUM_FILES=`cat ../helper_file | wc -l`
PORTION=$(($NUM_FILES/3))

i=0
cat ../helper_file | \
while read file_name; do
   i=$(($i+1 )) 
   if [ $i -ge $PORTION ] ; then break; fi 

   echo $file_name
done
```